# Как заблокировать остановку GIF-анимации при нажатии на ESC?

Tags: javascript, esc, события

Если на странице есть GIF-анимация, то в IE и FF при нажатии на ESC она останавливается.  Можно ли этого избежать средствами javascript?  Такой подход не помогает:

```
window.onkeyup=function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27){
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Здается мне что это эта фича вкручена в браузеры и не предотвращается средствами JS.

Comment: и это правильно

Comment: и за это ему +1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.onkeypress = document.keydown = function (event) {

    if ((event.which || event.keyCode) === 27) {
        event.preventDefault();

        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: скобка лишняя

Comment: @sercxjo обновил пост. Если не будет работать - значит точно не будет работать.

Comment: так работает (firefox 18.0), я разочарован в фф, как же теперь эту гадскую анимацию гасить если кто-то такое в свой сайт поставит...

Comment: Спасибо (нужно было по ESC блокировать только действия браузера по умолчанию и запускать свой обработчик, но это уже додумал сам)

Comment: @Rules и вы за рейтингом гоняетесь? Лучше бы уроки делали. Я ошибся, это нормально для людей.

Comment: Спасибо, сегодня я узнал, что можно останавливать GIF-анимации в браузере.